# Extract Data from a .txt File (PHP)

Tags: php, parsing

Using PHP, is there a better way of extracting the appropiate bits of information out of a text file without using strpos and substr PHP functions?

I need to extract the "Course xxx", No, and Ref

Example: The results for record with Subject of "Course 1...." would be:

- Course 1
- 8415
- 152

**Example .txt File:**

```
Name: Dave
Age: 15
Subject: Course 1 (No: 8415, Ref: #152#)
Description:

Description 1



Name: John
Age: 28
Subject: Course 2 (No: 646544, Ref: #325#)
Description:

Description 1



Name: Steve
Age: 22
Subject: Course 3 (No: 545, Ref: #451#)
Description:

Description 1
```

EDIT: Noticed I don't need all data extracted, but all data will still be in file.

Comment: I have used strpos and substr, but its messy imo

Comment: What's the 'Description 1' part? Rest is easy to extract with Regular Expressions. The question is... is the file consistent through out its entire structure? (Like the 2 enters which I can use as separators to help you with this) And is Description: Always a single line?

Comment: EDIT: I have just noticed I don't nedd all the data extracted, but all data will still be in file.

Comment: @Claudrian yes, the file is always in the same format, and the description is always on one line, with blank lines underneath.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(preg_match_all('~'.
    'Name:\\s*(?<Name>.+?)\r?\n'. // Name
    'Age:\\s*(?<Age>[0-9]+)\r?\n'. // Age
    'Subject:\\s*(?<Subject>.+?)\\s*\\('. // Subject
        'No:\\s*(?<No>[0-9]+)\\s*,'. // No
        '\\s*Ref:\\s*#(?<Ref>[0-9]+)#'. // Ref
    '\\)\r?\n'. // /Subject
    'Description:\\s*(?<Description>.+?)\r?\n'. // Description
'~si', $AccountDump, $Matches)){
    $Names = $Matches['Name'];
    $Ages = $Matches['Age'];
    $Subjects = $Matches['Subject'];
    $Nos = $Matches['No'];
    $Refs = $Matches['Ref'];
    $Descriptions = $Matches['Description'];
    $Accounts = array();
    foreach($Names as $Key => $Name){
        $Accounts[$Key] = array_map('trim', array(
            'Name'              => $Name,
            'Age'               => $Ages[$Key],
            'Subject'           => $Subjects[$Key],
            'No'                => $Nos[$Key],
            'Ref'               => $Refs[$Key],
            'Description'       => $Descriptions[$Key],
        ));
    }
    // Got them!
    var_dump($Accounts);
}
```

Load text in a variable named **$AccountDump**.

Have fun. Tested on your sample and it works.
I've split the RegExp so you can track it if you want.

*Hope it works!*

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use regular expressions for this. It will get a little complex, but won't be nearly as bad as `strpos` and `substr`.

As a starting point, here's a regular expression that will match name:value pairs -

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/^([^\s:]+):\s*(.+)$/m', $data, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Edit: I got curious and finished the regex, here it is in its entirety -

```
preg_match_all('/^([^\s:]+):\s*(.+?)(?:\s*\(([^\s:]+):\s*(.+),\s*([^\s:]+):\s*(.+)\))?$/m', $data, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have

```
$data = file_get_contents("log.txt");
$data = array_chunk(array_filter(array_map("trim",explode(chr(13).chr(10).chr(13), $data))),2);
$lists = array();

foreach ( $data as $value ) {
    $list = array();
    foreach ( explode("\n", implode("", $value)) as $item ) {
        list($key, $value) = explode(":", $item);
        $list[trim($key)] = trim($value);
    }
    $lists[] = $list;
}
var_dump($lists);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'Name' => string 'Dave' (length=4)
      'Age' => string '15' (length=2)
      'Subject' => string 'Course 1 (No' (length=12)
      'Description' => string 'Description 1' (length=13)
  1 => 
    array
      'Name' => string 'John' (length=4)
      'Age' => string '28' (length=2)
      'Subject' => string 'Course 2 (No' (length=12)
      'Description' => string 'Description 1' (length=13)
  2 => 
    array
      'Name' => string 'Steve' (length=5)
      'Age' => string '22' (length=2)
      'Subject' => string 'Course 3 (No' (length=12)
      'Description' => string 'Description 1' (length=13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this two PHP functions:

[preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

[preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Comment: it's more a comment than an answer

Comment: Does any one know of a site that can gerate regular expressions for you? All you need to do is entered the match (the thing you are searching for.)?

Comment: http://regexpal.com/ can be very helpful when building regular expressions. The site was inspired by a commercial product, regexbuddy, which I've had a lot of success with over the years